# Install htop/atop in android device

Tags: android, linux

Is there any way to install htop and atop in my android device? ie for installing `atop` in my linux pc I can use `apt install atop` in a terminal. Similarly is there any way to install atop in my adb device?

Answer (score 5):

Install Termux from the play store.  Termux brings a complete linux environment and allows you to install linux tools using the "pkg" package manager.

Getting HTOP is as easy as this:

```
1) Install Termux from Playstore
2) Open Termux
3) type "pkg install htop"
4) type "htop"
```

Enjoy

Comment: It only list process of Termux without those of third party apps.

Comment: @user2284570 - but you can get memory and load overview of the system, so that's useful as well.

Comment: @Guss With recent versions of Android, it doesn t even list occupation of cpu.

Comment: Termux in PlayStore is no longer updated, so you better install the recent version provided e.g. on Fdroid: https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.termux/

Comment: @user2284570 Yeah, but that's Android's problem. On one side, it's a clever security mechanism (application isolation), on other side, it's terribly limiting. Apps cannot backup other apps' files, for example, or even just monitor their processes.

Answer (score 1):

alternative to htop to show all system processes you can use `top` command
from an `adb shell` as you mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Termux works, but it shows only apps rub by the termux session.

You need to chroot in the root of the system:

1. Run Termux
2. `pkg install tsu`
3. `tsudo chroot /`
4. `htop`

Comment: Please note: this only works if you phone is rooted and a "real" `su` is installed.

Answer (score 0):

The following has worked for me:

1. pkg install tsu
2. tsu chroot /
3. pkg install htop
4. htop

Executing "HTop" whenever Termux is started works for me.

Answer (score 0):

This way of htop helpful in finding actual system performance, Since its running on termux again a Java app will emulate a terminal like prompt there it will install htop. hence its not useful.